# Unable to insert into database but no error produced

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

Not inserting data into database and not getting any error

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(global::Employees.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString); 
        try
        {             
            string query = "INSERT INTO Employee (username,password,city,phone)";
            query += " VALUES (@username,@password,@city,@phone)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", listBox.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone.Text);
            connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Success add Employee");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally{
            connection.Close();
        }

}
```

Comment: What error you get ? What is the question ? Please be clarify the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Maybe you're inserting to the wrong database?

Comment: I do not see any error and when entering the database the added data does not appear

Comment: @HusseinMohamed. . . Try to debug will definitely help.

Comment: If you execute the same query in SQL server, does it insert?

Comment: Yes, he is entering

Answer (score -1):

Try this way will work as expected

```
               string connectionString = @"data source=WS-KIRON-01;initial catalog=TestDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";//Replace Your connection string


                using (var _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    _connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (username,password,city,phone)  VALUES (@username,@password,@city,@phone)", _connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "testuser");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "pass");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "TestCity");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", "TestPhone");
                        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        sqlDataReader.Close();
                    }

                    _connection.Close();

                }
```

> **Note:**
>
> 1. Check database Name on connection string,
> 2. table name and given parameter  for example `@username` should be same,
> 3. Make sure your syntax is correct.

Let me know if you have anymore concern.

Comment: how does it differ from his answer, besides the `using`  statement

Comment: As he cannot specified the error. I have tested his code with my sample and works as expected. That why post it as answer. You could have a try.

Comment: This answer is not remotely helpful. It doesn't execute the same query. Half the values to insert are missing.

Comment: Is it a valid reason for down vote? I have given him the way! OP hasn't mentioned his error!

Comment: I do not think statement #2 is correct...  you can name the parameters anything you want; they don't have to correspond to the field name.

Comment: @Hambone I mean if you specified 4 param  `username,password,city,phone` provide 4 (@username,@password,@city,@phone) which should be same as table defination.